# Calling External API in botkit

Tags: node.js, botkit, botkit-4

As I am new to botkit, I have created the bot locally as per the docs. But when it is trying to call an external API using axios, below error shows -

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Here is the code -

```
const { BotkitConversation } = require("botkit");
const { axios } = require("axios");

module.exports = function(controller) {
    const convo = new BotkitConversation('convo', controller);

    convo.before('default', async(convo, bot) => {
        axios.get(...https url...) //error line
        .then(function (response) {
          convo.setVar('api-response', response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    });

    convo.ask('What is your name?', async(response, convo, bot) => {
        console.log(`user name is ${ response }`);
      }, 'name');
    convo.addAction('msg');
    convo.addMessage('Hi {{vars.name}}! Welcome to my Botkit', 'msg');

}
```

Can someone point out what is wrong on this code?

Comment: what is your url link? (axios.get(...https url...)), i test your code with dummy restful api(http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees) and work for me( i use "axios": "^0.19.2" and "botkit": "^4.8.1")

Comment: thanks for trying... the issue was how axios is impoted. It worked when I import it like `const axios = require("axios");`